# How can I "cut" an even number sequence from a big number?

Tags: python, sequence

My program is supposed to do the following:

- Get the maximum length of an even number sequence in a big number,
- get the index the sequence starts with and get the sequence itself,
- if there is no even numbers print None

Most parts of the program are working, but there is few bugs, for example:

```
>>>Please enter a positive integer: 2300245
>>>The maximal length is 0
>>>Sequence starts at 2
>>>Sequence is []
```

This is my code:

```
num = int(input("Please enter a positive integer: "))

length=0
seq=[None]
start = -1
maxlength=0
maxstart=-1
even=['0','2','4','6','8']


for index,i in enumerate(str(num)):
    if i in even:
        length+=1
        if length==1:
            start=index
        seq+=[i]
    else:
        if length>maxlength:
            maxlength=length
            maxstart=start
        seq=[]
        length=0



print("The maximal length is", length)
print("Sequence starts at", start)
print("Sequence is", seq)
```

Comment: Huh? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "even number sequence". It would help if you included what it was "supposed" to print out in addition to what it's "not supposed" to print.

Comment: This is what it's supposed to print:
Please enter a positive integer: 2300245 
The maximal length is 4 
Sequence starts at 2 
Sequence is 0024

Answer (score 0):

When you see a new value in the string you set `seq` to be empty. In the same way that you save the length as `maxlength` you should also save the sequence in a variable, as you reset `seq`at the same time as `length`.

Answer (score 0):

```
seq = []
start = -1

num = int(input("Please entrer a positive integer: "))

for idx, value in enumerate(str(num)):
    # Test if value is even
    if int(value) % 2 == 0:
        if len(seq) == 0:
            start = idx
        seq.append(value)

print "The maximal length is %i" % len(seq)
print "Sequence starts at %i" % start
print "Sequence is %s" % seq
```

Or even, using a list comprehension :

```
num = int(input("Please entrer a positive integer: "))

seq = [value for value in str(num) if int(value) % 2 == 0]
start = str(num).index(seq[0]) if len(seq) > 0 else -1

print "The maximal length is %i" % len(seq)
print "Sequence starts at %i" % start
print "Sequence is %s" % seq
```

This code returns :

```
Please entrer a positive integer: 256387456
The maximal length is 5
Sequence starts at 0
Sequence is ['2', '6', '8', '4', '6']
```

Is this is what you want?